# How I can creating all the tables, a trigger must be written so that the IDs are entered automatically

Tags: oracle

```
Create Table table8_prc (
                          Family    VARCHAR2(200),
                        
                          Name      VARCHAR2(200) ,
                          
                          ID        INTEGER 
                       

                           ) ;
                           
CREATE SEQUENCE ID_seq1
  MINVALUE 1
  START WITH 1
  INCREMENT BY 1
  CACHE 20;  
  
Create or Replace trigger trg1 
  BEFORE insert on  table8_prc 
  
   for each row 
   BEGIN
   select ID_seq1.nextval into :new.ID from dual ;
   END ;
 
   


 CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE addnewmem1 (str IN VARCHAR2)
   AS
    BEGIN
      INSERT INTO table8_prc (Name, Family)
          WITH
            temp
             AS
              (    SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR (str,
                                           '[^,]+',
                                          1,
                                          LEVEL) val
                     FROM DUAL
                CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT (str, ',') + 1)
        SELECT  ID,SUBSTR (val, 1, INSTR (val, ';') - 1),
                SUBSTR (val, INSTR (val, ';') + 1)
           FROM temp;
 
      COMMIT;
   END;
   
   

 BEGIN
       addnewmem1 ('faezeh;Ghanbarian,pari;izadi');
    END;
    
BEGIN
       addnewmem1 ('Saeed;Izadi,Saman; Rostami');
       
    END;
```

Comment: What is the version of your Oracle DBMS? For 12+ you may use `id generated always as identity` and do not use any triggers or manually specify sequence values

Comment: Also please note that it a bad practice to store lists as CSV string. Use appropriate datatype, for example `sys.odcivarchar2list`

Answer (score 0):

You're close. Fix number of columns to be inserted.

Table, sequence and trigger:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE table8_prc
  2  (
  3     Family   VARCHAR2 (200),
  4     Name     VARCHAR2 (200),
  5     ID       INTEGER
  6  );

Table created.

SQL> CREATE SEQUENCE ID_seq1 MINVALUE 1 START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 CACHE 20;

Sequence created.

SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg1
  2     BEFORE INSERT
  3     ON table8_prc
  4     FOR EACH ROW
  5  BEGIN
  6     SELECT ID_seq1.NEXTVAL INTO :new.ID FROM DUAL;
  7  END;
  8  /

Trigger created.
```

Procedure:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE addnewmem1 (str IN VARCHAR2)
  2  AS
  3  BEGIN
  4     INSERT INTO table8_prc (Name, Family)
  5        WITH
  6           temp
  7           AS
  8              (    SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR (str,
  9                                         '[^,]+',
 10                                         1,
 11                                         LEVEL) val
 12                     FROM DUAL
 13               CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT (str, ',') + 1)
 14        SELECT TRIM (SUBSTR (val, 1, INSTR (val, ';') - 1)),
 15               TRIM (SUBSTR (val, INSTR (val, ';') + 1))
 16          FROM temp;
 17
 18     COMMIT;
 19  END;
 20  /

Procedure created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> BEGIN
  2     addnewmem1 ('faezeh;Ghanbarian,pari;izadi');
  3     addnewmem1 ('Saeed;Izadi,Saman; Rostami');
  4  END;
  5  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> SELECT * FROM table8_prc;

FAMILY               NAME                         ID
-------------------- -------------------- ----------
Ghanbarian           faezeh                        1
izadi                pari                          2
Izadi                Saeed                         3
Rostami              Saman                         4

SQL>
```